# Xcode Project Template: Only add file to filesystem

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

I want my custom Xcode template to add a `.gitignore` file to the project directory (on the filesystem), but I don't want the `.gitignore` file to be added to the project, e.g., the Project Navigator, at all. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm currently wondering about this too. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not possible. I tried creating a <definition> for a gitignore, but it's only added if you add a <Nodes> entry to go with it. And if you add something in <Nodes> It automatically gets added to the project. I suppose that's the point.